Was the Buddha an atheist, theist or agnostic?
In relation to a creator god, was the Buddha an atheist, theist or agnostic? Please provide answers with quotes from Buddhist scriptures.


Buddha was not atheist or theist or agnostic. He was pragmatic. He talked about manifestation or presence or occurrence of Suffering. How suffering originates, and brilliantly answers can suffering be ended ? As YES!!! Then he goes on to say What does it take to end suffering?
Buddha’ dependent Origination applies to all phenomena. Whether it is God , Devil , Human , Monkey , Insect ,Fish, Dog , Horse , Male , Female ,Diseases etc …dependent origination applies to all Dhamma. This dependent origination of suffering must cease.
This is done by cutting off the cravings.
Craving to become or not to become.
This is what Buddha talks about with respect to all creatures in heaven , hell or earth!!( Including Gods)
